# Conditionally setting session variables in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, session-variables

I am new to Laravel. I have a table of information and a master view page (master.blade.php). All the other views extend it. I want to see if certain session variables exist and if not set them. This is to stop reading a table unnecessarily. In standard PHP I would write:

```
<?php
if  ( !isset($_SESSION['name'] )) {
    $db = new smplPDO();
    $co = $db->get_row('config',array(), array() );
    $_SESSION['name'] = $co['name'] ;
    $_SESSION['thisyear'] = ReturnCurrentYear() ;
}
?>
```

How can I test the master view and set them if necessary so they can be used elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked it out:

```
if  ( !session()->has('name'))
    {
    $db = new smplPDO();
    $co = $db->get_row('config',array(), array() );
    session()->put('name',$co['name']);
    session()->put('thisyear',ReturnCurrentYear());
}
```